# Mi expresión regular siempre arroja un falso, por que?

Tags: java, regex, java-8

Es un programa en java muy sencillo de dos partes, la primera parte es evaluar si un sitio web ingresado es correcto, esta la evalúa muy bien y no hay mayor problema.

El detalle esta cuando quiero ver si hay algunas coincidencias que den indicio de una pagina peligrosa o de mala índole. Pero siempre me arroja falso, que no hay matches.

Aquí mi código:

Método para ver si es url valida (Aquí todo bien):

```
public static boolean isValidWeb (String url) {
    return url.matches("^https?:\\/\\/[\\w\\-]+(\\.[\\w\\-]+)+[/#?]?.*$");
}
//Evaluó en otro if para ver si todo correcto
if(isValidWeb(textField.getText().toString())) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btnNewButton, "Es una url valida");
}
```

Pero al momento de ver si alguna parte de la url es "sospechosa", no me retorna un true (Como indicio de que si encontró coincidencia). Retorna un false y por ende al validar en el otro if, me dice que no hay nada malo.

```
    public static boolean isWrongWeb (String url) {
    return Pattern.matches("[xxx|porn|caliente|ad|cpm|onion|owl|t2mio|bl.ink|leaks|magic4you]", url);
}
if (isWrongWeb(url)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btnNewButton, "Advertencia, parece ser un sitio web malicioso");
}else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btnNewButton, "Sitio web completamente seguro");
}
```

Siempre retorna falso y por ende me dice que es seguro el sitio.

La prueba la hago con la cadena (como nombre de una web): htts://porn.xxx. (el error ortografico en el sitio es a proposito)

Comment: y si para wrong web le pones greedy matchers? ".*[xxx|porn|caliente|ad|cpm|onion|owl|t2mio|bl.ink|leaks|magic4you].*"

Comment: No, no funciono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira, tu error sucede ya que RegEx evalúa, en tu caso, a la cadena entera.
Y lo que estas haciendo es básicamente comparar toda tu cadena de prueba ("htts://porn.xxx") con alguna de las palabras a evaluar.

"htts://porn.xxx" para nada se parece a "xxx", o a "porn", o a "bl.onk", etc.
Por ello siempre arroja un falso.

Por lo que leo en tu pregunta, quieres hacer un "analizador" de sitios web que sean maliciosos por su dominio. De ser asi, tienes muchas maneras de solucionar eso.

Hagámoslo trabajando con la cadena, y saquemos de la url al dominio. Asumiré que eres novato, por ello el código que te pondré será entendible para ti.
Usaremos un for para analizar cada uno de los caracteres de la cadena, dentro de: delimitaremos la parte en la que esta el dominio (htts://porn.xxx) y lo pondremos en otra variable. En este caso el dominio esta entre "/", y ".".
Así que en base a una bandera, si esta activa, indicara que estamos dentro del dominio e ir almacenando cada carácter, si no, que no haga nada.

```
String url = "htts://porn.xxx";
            String dominio = "";
            boolean bandera = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < url.length(); i++) {
                if(url.charAt(i) == '/') {
                    bandera = true;
                }
                
                if(bandera == true && url.charAt(i) == '.') {
                    bandera = false;
                }
                
                if(bandera == true && url.charAt(i) != '/') {
                    dominio = dominio+url.charAt(i);
                }
            
            }
```

Hay tres "if's", el primero es para iniciar la bandera en true y obtener el dominio.

El segundo es para preguntar que si el caracter es "." y si la bandera esta en true; pasarlo a falso. Ya que aqui termino el dominio.

El tercero es para: Que si la bandera es verdadera (Que estamos en el dominio), que el carácter evaluando en cuestión, se anexe a nuestro dominio que llevamos. Nótese que adjuntamos la condición de que el carácter sea diferente a "/"; esto por que el iniciar el dominio, aun nos queda otra "/" y esa no la queremos en el dominio.

De este modo tenemos el dominio, y ya puedes ver si se parece a alguna "mala  palabra" de tu lista con el método que ya tenias.

Pero te hare un nuevo metodo mas "formal" para que lo entiendas.

```
public static boolean isWrongWeb (String url) {
    final String palabras = "xxx|porn|caliente|ad|cpm|onion|owl|t2mio|bl.ink|leaks|magic4you";
    if (url.matches("(\\W)*(" + palabras +")")) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Y de ese modo, ya funciona tu programa.
Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias!!!!, funciono.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes tratar de encontrar coincidencias en cualquier lugar de la cadena:

```
public static boolean isWrongWeb (String url) {
    return url.matches(".*(xxx|porn|caliente|ad|cpm|onion|owl|t2mio|bl.ink|leaks|magic4you).*")
}
```

Comment: Gracias, también funciona!